# Creating directory and deleting it in the end

Tags: java, file

I know the basic syntax for creating and deleting directories. I am in a strange situation, so any help will be really helpful.

I create the directories as shown below:

```
if (!dir.exists()) {
   dir.mkdir();
}
else 
   System.out.println("hfuiwedsjcz");
```

I create a directory, and inside the directory I have more than one file. I write to those files and perform several operations on the files inside the directory.
I want to write a program to create the directory, such as the directory is deleted after I have written and read the files inside it (So as to avoid deleting the folder manually).

I am assuming it is a recursive process, where I first create folder and then delete it. Now when I run the next time, I should not be having any folder, rather it should be created again and deleted in the end.

How would I do this?

Comment: You can use Apachesc commons http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#deleteDirectory%28java.io.File%29 to delete the directory. It will delete all the folders/files inside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to use the [`deleteOnExit()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit%28%29) method from the `File` class. Invoke this on each directory and file as you create them.

It will delete the files when the JVM exists in the reverse order that you registered the files.

```
if (!dir.exists()) {
   dir.mkdir();
   dir.deleteOnExit();
}

// etc...
```

Comment: Can this be accomplished on any number of Directories? I create more than ten directories in a loop and want to delete after reading the files and editing the files inside. When I run the code with dir.deleteOnExit(); the files are deleted before performing the related operations, resulting in a FileNotFoundException. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: @MohammedIrfan The files will not be deleted until the JVM exits. You must have a different error in your code.

Comment: Can you be a little precise on what do you mean by "JVM exits". This is the solution that I wanted, it is deleting files, but not all. So if you can explain what do you mean by "JVM exits", it could help me a lot. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey @Duncan Jones.. I found the Solution. Thanks a lot again. It helped. Cheers.

Comment: deleteOnExit has a [memory leak](http://nineofclouds.blogspot.com/2013/08/pdf-service-memory-leaks.html) in it. If you're using it in a web context, avoid it!

Comment: @mbarlocker The function does *not* have a memory leak in it. It works exactly as is documented. The page you linked is describing a programming error (i.e. thinking `deleteOnExit` is a good choice in their environment) rather than a bug in the function.

Answer (score 1):

How about just presume that the directory will be once created and at every run, at the end you would just clean-up the directory (empty the directory)?
This might help you:

[FileUtils.cleanDirectory](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#cleanDirectory%28java.io.File%29)

Or as you wish, you can go for:

[FileUtils.forceMkdir()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#forceMkdir%28java.io.File%29)

And at the end either:

[FileUtils.deleteDirectory()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#deleteDirectory%28java.io.File%29)
or

[FileUtils.forceDeleteOnExit()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#forceDeleteOnExit%28java.io.File%29)

This is similar to what the other people responded, but this would be the easier way of going if you are using jdk 1.6 and not 1.7 (unfortunately, there a lot of people still using 1.6)

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.io.File.deleteOnExit()` on each created File object. You need to start from the first directory, you create and call it for every used `File` object.